# Jetty Class-loading Issue

Tags: spring-boot, classloader, jetty-9

I have a Spring Boot Application, which I want to deploy as a war file in jetty 9.0.7.
I am getting spring jar conflict issue,
In jetty start.ini refers to a lib folder with lower version of spring jar for another project,which cant be changed.

But How I can force jetty to ignore those jar & use own WEB-INF/lib jars.

I tried to use in jetty-web.XML but it's not working.
Any other way ?

```
 <Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/EmiratesIDProxy</Set>
<Set name="parentLoaderPriority">true</Set>
<Call name="prependServerClass">
        <Arg>-org.springframework.org.</Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```